# Parsing a Dynamic Web Page using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to parse a WebPage whose html source code changes when I press a arrow-key to get a drop-down list. 
I want to parse the contents of that drop down list. How can I do that?

Example of the Problem: If you go to this site: http://in.bookmyshow.com/hyderabad and select the arrow button on comboBox "Select Movie" a drop-down list of movies appears. I want to get a list of these movies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not getting html tags, There is JavaScript written to show monies list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/). It allows you to reproduce exacly the same steps as you do because it also uses the browser (Firefox, Chrome, etc).

Ofc, it's not as fast as using mechanize, urllib, beautifulsoup and all this stuff, but it is worth a try.

Answer (score 3):

The actual URL with the data used to populate the drop-down box is here:

- [http://in.bookmyshow.com/getJSData/?file=/data/js/GetEvents_MT.js&cmd=GETEVENTSWEB&et=MT&rc=HYD&*=1425299159643&*=1425299159643](http://in.bookmyshow.com/getJSData/?file=/data/js/GetEvents_MT.js&cmd=GETEVENTSWEB&et=MT&rc=HYD&_=1425299159643&_=1425299159643)

I'd be a bit careful though and double-check with the site terms of use or if there are any APIs that you could use instead.

Comment: Great Man..!!!! Thanks a ton. :)
Can you please help me knowing how did you get this URL..???

Comment: Sure, if you're using Chrome, press `F12`, then switch to the `Network` tab. Reload the page and you will see all the requests that your browser made while loading the page. Finding the right request is now just a matter of manually inspecting this list and their responses. Feel free to accept this answer as the correct one if it helped you ;) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to dig into the JavaScript to see how that menu gets populated. If it is getting populated via AJAX, then it might be easy to get that content by re-doing a request to the same URL (e.g., do a GET to "http://www.example.com/get_dropdown_entries.php").